# Wordpress, how do I prevent archive pages from applying pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to stop pagination of a certain archive page in wordpress that renders /services/page/2/, /services/page/3/ up to 5 that shouldn't be there.

I have tried multiple recommended solutions but nothing seems to work. The function I have in my functions.php file that makes the most sense is

```
function wpse_disable_pagination($query)
{
    if ($query->is_post_type_archive()) {
        $query->set('nopaging', true);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_disable_pagination');
```

But this doesn't produce any results.
How do I stop the paging but instead produce a 404?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing that probably has to do with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/#a-warning-about-conditional-functions

Comment: List all posts on archive and that will remove the pagination. Another way is for custom posts to set has_archive to false and use template to create query for your cpt if you want to list them. Or check this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304137/disable-pagination-in-posts-and-pages .

Comment: From your code `$query->is_post_type_archive()` this must be giving false. You might need to use different condition. Can you please check without that condition to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to figure this out as well. Most of my archives are multi page but I use ajax and a load more button to load more results from the query. I notice in my source that the page gets a rel=next link and those URLs for different pages still actually work.

```
<link rel="next" href="/services/page/2/">
```

Wondering how to turn this off and still keep multiple pages working with the archives root page for those that use ajax to load in the query results.